# mysql cluster manager : Unable to connect to mysql client instance mysql cluster 7.5.5

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I followed steps mentioned in below link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04

- Mysql cluster manager 7.5.5 is installed on nodes and server manager
- Created the conf file for mysql cluster manager, mentioned below
- Created mysql user and group
- Executed ( mysql-cluster/config.ini ) on cluster manager
- Ran the same steps on the node 1 and node 2
- Installed mysql server and clients on node 1 and node 2
- Executed ( mysql-cluster/config.ini ) on node 1 and node 2
- Node 1 and Node 2 gave expected output when ran ndb - moving on to cluster manger
- Over cluster manager, unable to run mysql command; needed this inorder to test how the cluster works overall with the local server and servers on node 1 and node 2

Below is the conf file of mysql cluster manager

```
[ndb_mgmd]
# Management process options:
hostname=sit-mysql-manager-hostname.com  # Hostname of the manager
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for the log files

[ndbd]
hostname=sit-mysql-node1-hostname.com    # Hostname of the first data node
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[ndbd]
hostname=sit-mysql-node2-hostname.com   # Hostname of the second data node
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Remote directory for the data files

[mysqld]
# SQL node options:
hostname=sit-mysql-manager-hostname.com  # In our case the MySQL server/client is on the same Droplet as the cluster manager
```

Node1 and Node 2 are up and running. Mysql cluster manager could connect to those nodes.

[image: NDB manager and mysql output]

Unable to connect to Mysql cluster manager's mysql client present in the manager server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have changed selinux settings.

perform-

```
setenforce 0
```

`getenforce` - o/p of this should be
permissive

for permanent setup-
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html